# Xfce notes background

Tags: xfce, desktop-background, transparency, notes

I tried  xfce Notes and liked it a lot. This lightweight app does the job and the backups are easy (all notes are located in ~/.local/share/notes/). Is it possible to remove transparency and change background to white?

Thanks in advance

PS
I've tried gnote, but export of notes seems to be a problem there (rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt didn't work for me).

Comment: I was talking about an app called Notes 1.8.1.

Comment: Actually, gnote can export all notes  by "syncronize", so I will just switch to gnote.

Comment: If you right click on the tray icon and click Properties, you can see that they now have background color options built into the xfce4-notes app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the settings would not keep until I disabled this GTK file. However, I would still keep a copy as done below.

```
cd /usr/share/xfce4-notes-plugin/gtk-2.0/
sudo mv notes.gtkrc notes.gtkrc.backup
```

Now choose your favorite text editor. I use gedit.

```
gedit ~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-notes.rc
```

Change line #10 to

```
Transparency=0
```

Launch Notes. Enjoy the white background. This would be my preference too!

(Extra note) If for some strange reason this does not work, in `~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-notes.gtkrc` change `notes_bg_color` and `notes_selected_bg_color` to `#ffffffffffff`

Comment: But we can't set individual note background color?

Comment: I doubt that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to start using Gnote, because it is just as convenient and provides additional features (html editing, links, etc).